# How to define a cluster key based on a expression in Snowflake?

Tags: data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As per Snowflake documentation (https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html) a cluster key can be defined as one or more table columns/expressions.
The example they bring is:

```
-- cluster by expressions
create or replace table t2 (c1 timestamp, c2 string, c3 number) cluster by (to_date(c1), substring(c2, 0, 10));
```

I want to extract from a date column the year,month and day and to create a cluster key based on those expressions, but didn't find a workaround.
This is what i tried already:

```
 CREATE TABLE TBL_DATECREATED  (DATECREATED_UTC)  
 CLUSTER BY (
              TO_DATE(DATECREATED_UTC)
              )  
 AS
 SELECT DATECREATED_UTC FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS
```

**Result:**

```
 SQL compilation error: invalid type [TO_DATE(TBL_DATECREATED.DATECREATED_UTC)] for parameter 'TO_DATE'
```

---

> **Mention: `SELECT TO_DATE(DATECREATED_UTC) FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS` works fine!

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATECREATED (DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS)
CLUSTER BY ( year(DATECREATED_UTC)
             -- extract(year from DATECREATED_UTC)
             ,EMAILADDRESS
            )
AS
SELECT DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS
```

**Result:**

```
SQL compilation error: Function EXTRACT does not support UNKNOWN argument type
(for commented expression i received the same error message)
```

---

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATECREATED (DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS)
CLUSTER BY (  DATECREATED_UTC
             ,substring(EMAILADDRESS, 1, 3)
            )
AS
SELECT DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS
```

**Result:**

```
SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 14 Invalid argument types for function 'SUBSTRING': (UNKNOWN, NUMBER(1,0), NUMBER(1,0))
```

Thanks in advance for each suggestion/solution!

Comment: Based on your post...is DATECREATED_UTC a timestamp?  You don't specify it in your create table statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use the below statements to define a cluster key based on the expression for a materialized view.

```
CREATE or replace MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATECREATED (DATECREATED_UTC,EMAILADDRESS) cluster by(DATECREATED_UTC,EMAILADDRESS ) AS SELECT to_date(DATECREATED_UTC), EMAILADDRESS FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS;

CREATE or replace MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATECREATED (DATECREATED_UTC,EMAILADDRESS) cluster by(DATECREATED_UTC,EMAILADDRESS ) AS SELECT DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS;

alter materialized view MV_DATECREATED cluster by(TO_DATE(DATECREATED_UTC),EMAILADDRESS );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, when you define the clustering key at the same time as you create the table maybe Snowflake isn't able to determine the datatype of the column properly?

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATECREATED (DATECREATED_UTC timestamp, EMAILADDRESS varchar)
CLUSTER BY ( year(DATECREATED_UTC)
             -- extract(year from DATECREATED_UTC)
             ,EMAILADDRESS
            )
AS
SELECT DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS
```

Comment: Note: you do not need to declare the data type in the column_list section of this statement.  It will use the data type of the base table or from whatever casting might be in the SELECT statement.

Comment: It does, though.  :-)  It's possible that there was an issue and it has been fixed, but the documentation is correct in this case: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-materialized-view.html#optional-parameters

Comment: Right, when a MV is created  it will use the data type of the base table. So, the next query is absolutely valid one! (verified):
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATECREATED (DATECREATED_UTC , EMAILADDRESS )
CLUSTER BY (
              DATECREATED_UTC
             ,EMAILADDRESS
            )
AS
SELECT DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, try adding a datatype to the create table.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_DATECREATED  (DATECREATED_UTC timestamptz)
```

For the second and third issues, check that the data types are what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks @waldente! It worked for  CREATE TABLE  statement and i was able to use expressions in CLUSTER KEY after i added the datatype.

Comment: Regarding MATERIALIZED VIEWS: still doesn't work! This is what i've tried:
`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATECREATED (DATECREATED_UTC TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), EMAILADDRESS VARCHAR(254))
CLUSTER BY (
              TO_DATE(DATECREATED_UTC)
             ,EMAILADDRESS
            )
AS
SELECT DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS `  **Result:** _SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 41 unexpected 'DATECREATED_UTC'._

Comment: It works just in this format:
`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATECREATED (DATECREATED_UTC , EMAILADDRESS )
CLUSTER BY (
              DATECREATED_UTC
             ,EMAILADDRESS
            )
AS
SELECT DATECREATED_UTC, EMAILADDRESS FROM BASETABLE_CONTACTS`
Any other idea?